# LilyJazz major 7 triangle symbol

Tags: notation, lilypond

I'm getting started using lilyjazz to write Jazz-styled music. I'd like to get the Realbook-like notation that I'm used to featuring a triangle to denote a major seven.

the `jazzchords.ily` stylesheet comes in pretty handy, but I'm struggling to find a proper substitution for the "M":

```
% for major chords, use "acMaj" to print a small "M"
#(define-markup-command (acMaj layout props extension) (string?)
  (interpret-markup layout props
    (markup #:super "M" #:super extension)))
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't know lilyjazz.  It looks like a programming language (interesting).  Is there a manual with character definitions?  If not I'd recommend you look at unicode characters.  This handles Greek characters, so you can get a capital delta, which is a triangle.  If lilyjazz is unicode compatible that would do it.

Comment: By the way, unicode for cap delta is U+0394.  try it and see what you get, there are other codes of this.  I can direct you to more.  But google unicode and find the website for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a triangle figure in the `lilyjazz` fonts, so following ggcg's comments, you could try altering `jazzchords.ily` to have instead:

```
% for major chords, use "acMaj" to print a small triangle
#(define-markup-command (acMaj layout props extension) (string?)
  (interpret-markup layout props
    (markup #:super #:char 916 #:super extension)))
```

Whether this mix of Unicode with the `lilyjazz` font is aesthetically superior is up to you.

Comment: thank you, that works. Too bad the font does not yet contain the triangle